# Extracting data using fetch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to read a locally stored text file using javascript. I need to pass the information stored on the text file to pass through evaluations for test result. Since I could not access the text file directly, I have hosted it on to a local server and trying to fetch data using the URL.

Here is how my code looks like -

```js
const mediaFile = 'http://localhost:8080/' + fileName; 
function MediaInfo(file) {
  fetch(file)
  .then(function (response) {
    response.text();
  })
 .then(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   return response.data();
 });
}

const a = MediaInfo(mediaFile);
await browser.expect(a).eql(44);

    });
```

But the calling of function MediaInfo(mediaFile) returns undefined. Any idea why I cant get the data returned??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function inside the second `then` is returning some data, but `MediaInfo` itself isn't returning anything.

Since you have one `await` already, I'd suggest going fully async/await:

```js
async function MediaInfo(file) {
  const response = await fetch(file);
  const text = await response.text();
  console.log(text);
  return text;
}
```

Also note that in order to avoid variables storing `Promise`s, you'd probably want to change to

```
const a = await MediaInfo(mediaFile);
```

Comment: Also note you'd need to change to `const a = await MediaInfo(mediaFile);`