# javascript automatically read the file in the same directory, and put it on the content

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, onload

is it possible on HTML page load, automatically (without the user input)read the file in the same directory, and put it on the content?

consider text file (a.txt) in the same folder as my HTML file (index.html)

for example

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
    const fileText = await fetch("a.txt").text();
    const tagElement = document.getElementById("about_layer");
    tagElement.innerText = fileText; 
    }
```

add HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" >
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"  defer>     
 
 async function getTextFile1() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/a.txt");
    const fileText = await response.text();
    const tagElement = document.getElementById("about_layer");
    tagElement.innerText = fileText; 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
 }
 
   async function getTextFile() {
    const fileText = await fetch("a.txt").text();
    const tagElement = document.getElementById("about_layer");
    tagElement.innerText = fileText;
}

window.onload = getTextFile1;
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div  >hsfghfghdfghdfg
   </div>
   <div id="about_layer">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code does not make any sense, FileReader and a fetch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71376011/extracting-data-using-fetch-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a `Promise` that resolves to a `Response` object. If you want to decode the response as text, then you'll have to await the `text()` method as it also returns a `Promise`, which resolves to a string.

As for *on page load*, just make sure you add a `defer` tag to your script to ensure that your script is called after the DOM is loaded.

```
(async function() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("./a.txt", {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    });
    const fileText = await response.text();
    const tagElement = document.getElementById("about_layer");
    tagElement.innerText = fileText; 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}())
```

```
<script src="yourscript.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: tnx for the tip, can you add more detail about how to add a defer tag to your script to ensure that your script is called after the DOM is loaded

Comment: it doesn't work    "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"

Comment: Can you give more info about the *why* the request failed? Like error codes and messages?

Comment: I add my html code , can you use an arbitrary a.txt file to see what error is produced

Comment: Please don't modify the question with the provided answer; this makes the answer and the question look strange for anyone not familiar with our discussion. You can see information in the `network` tab of your browser or even in the console for that matter. If you don't know how to debug your code, then this is a chance to learn it.

Comment: I add comments to clear the question not change, also I know how to use the debug code, I've just intended to reduce miscommunication, this is the error code from console " Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/a.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, chrome-untrusted, https, isolated-app."

Comment: Try changing the Fetch call to `await fetch('/a.txt', { mode: 'no-cors' });` and see if it runs.

Comment: GET file:///C:/a.txt net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
I think GET file does not guarantee to look in the same directory

Comment: `./a.text` should look in the same dir as the JS file is being executed.

Comment: I used the following command to be sure select the file , the error ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND gone but nothing is displayed myfile=location.href.slice(0,location.href.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/a.txt"